# Python pyplot histogram: Adjusting bin width, Not number of bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bins

I have been able to make myself a pretty little histogram that looks like this:

[image: One day it will be pretty]

I was able to produce the image with the following code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.figure()  
    plt.axis([0, 6000, 0, 45000])  

    data['column'][data.value == 0].hist(bins=200, label='A') 
    data['column2'][data.value == 1].hist(bins=200, label='B')

    plt.title('A Histogram')  
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')  
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')  
    plt.legend()  

    return plt
```

Which is all fine and good, but the bins are not equal lengths. The only way I have been able to get the bins at equal lengths is to do something like this:

```
 bins=[0,100,200,300,400,.......)
```

Which is not pretty at all.

I have googled a bit and looked around here. The most popular answer to a similar question is [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram/%22this%20guy%22) which suggests a seemingly excellent answer that I can not get to work for the life of me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a bit confused with your data structure and how you are calling the function `hist`. However, I suppose you are using matplotib, so you need to define the same binning range for the `hist` function. It works better if you pass an array with the bin boundaries, instead of the number of bins you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()  
plt.axis([0, 6000, 0, 45000])  

# From your example I am assuming that the maximum value is 6000
binBoundaries = np.linspace(0,6000,201)

data['column'][data.value == 0].hist(bins=binBoundaries, label='A') 
data['column2'][data.value == 1].hist(bins=binBoundaries, label='B')

plt.title('A Histogram')  
plt.xlabel('x-axis')  
plt.ylabel('y-axis')  
plt.legend()
```

This should work for you.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. That did it. I thought that I had tried that before, but apparently I had not. Thanks!