# How to change bin width in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

For example i have next situation:
[image]

but i want that width for each bin was bigger.
something like this:
[image]

so target is just adjust width  for each bin

code is :

```
    x_axis_values = []
    for i in range(-50, 51, 1):
        x_axis_values.append(i)
    pl.xticks((np.arange(-50, 50, 1)), rotation=45, fontsize=5)
    pl.yticks(fontsize=10)
    pl.hist(deltas, bins=x_axis_values, color='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)
    pl.title('Histogramm md_latency_is_bigger|0|main_latency_is_bigger')
    pl.xlabel('deltas value, ms')
    pl.ylabel('delta count, cnt')
    pl.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')
    pl.savefig('HISTOGRAMM.png')
    pl.show()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how i can adjust width for bins?

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) how the bins are used.

If you want to change the bin width - you could change the step size in your x-axis:

```py
stepsize = 20

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

x_axis_values = []
x_axis_values = np.arange(-50, 51, stepsize)
plt.xticks((np.arange(-50, 50, 20)), rotation=45, fontsize=5)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10)
plt.hist(deltas, bins=x_axis_values, color='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.title('Histogramm md_latency_is_bigger|0|main_latency_is_bigger')
plt.xlabel('deltas value, ms')
plt.ylabel('delta count, cnt')
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')
plt.savefig('HISTOGRAMM.png')
plt.show()
```

producing a *wider figure with bigger bins*:

[image]

Also see this question if it helps you:

- [Adjust bin width not number of bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101623/python-pyplot-histogram-adjusting-bin-width-not-number-of-bins)

---

As the documentation states:

> If bins is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin

So you need to create a sequence, fitting your needs. [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange) can be useful for that.

Comment: for my case i need step = 1 and also increase width

Comment: How is this possible? When the stepsize is constant, you set the width. 
Do you maybe only want to extend the figures to see the bin width a bit bigger?

Comment: Yes sure! Exactly, sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: see adapted code above... You need to set the figure size accordingly.