# matplotlib histogram with frequency and counts

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data (from a space delimited text file with two columns)  which is already binned but only a width of 1.  I want to increase this width to about 5.  How can I do this using numpy/matplotlib in Python?

Using,

```
data = loadtxt('file.txt')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
plt.bar(x,y)
```

creates too many bars and using,

```
plt.hist(data)
```

doesn't plot the histogram appropriately.  I guess I don't understand how matplotlib's histogram plotting works.

See some of the data below.

```
264 1
265 1
266 4
267 2
268 2
269 2
270 2
271 2
272 5
273 3
274 2
275 6
276 7
277 3
278 7
279 5
280 9
281 4
282 8
283 11
284 9
285 15
286 19
287 11
288 12
289 10
290 13
291 18
292 20
293 14
294 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use `numpy.reshape` to transform your data before using `plt.bar`, for example:

```
In [83]: import numpy as np

In [84]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [85]: data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,3,8,9,1,2]]).T

In [86]: data
Out[86]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 8],
       [4, 9],
       [5, 1],
       [6, 2]])

In [87]: y = data[:,1].reshape(-1,2).sum(axis=1)

In [89]: y
Out[89]: array([ 7, 17,  3])


In [91]: x = data[:,0].reshape(-1,2).mean(axis=1)

In [92]: x
Out[92]: array([ 1.5,  3.5,  5.5])

In [96]: plt.bar(x, y)
Out[96]: <Container object of 3 artists>

In [97]: plt.show()
```

Comment: Please don't use `pylab` use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` for plotting and `import numpy as np` for math.

Comment: @tcaswell, why? what's wrong with `pylab`? I get the same results.

Comment: Because it bulk imports all manner of things.  If there were not so many examples around we would deprecate it.

Comment: It also greatly confuses _where_ functions come from.  MPL gets a non-zero number of bug reports that really should be going to numpy.

Comment: Thank you! :)  Made the internet that much of a more accurate place

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert at matplotlib but I find `hist` to be incredibly useful. The examples on the [matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html) give a great overview of some of the features.

I don't know how to use your provided sample data without transforming it. I altered your example to dequantize those data before creating a histogram.

I calculated the bin size using [this question's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('file.txt')
dequantized = data[:,0].repeat(data[:,1].astype(int))

dequantized[0:7]
# Each row's first column is repeated the number of times found in the
# second column creating a single array.
# array([ 264.,  265.,  266.,  266.,  266.,  266.,  267.])

def bins(xmin, xmax, binwidth, padding):
    # Returns an array of integers which can be used to represent bins
    return np.arange(
        xmin - (xmin % binwidth) - padding,
        xmax + binwidth + padding,
        binwidth)

histbins = bins(min(dequantized), max(dequantized), 5, 5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(dequantized, histbins)
plt.show()
```

This histogram displayed looks like this.
[image: Histogram with a binwidth of 5]

I hope this example is useful.