# Python & Matplotlib: how to speficy unit when ploting histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `datafram` like this:
[image]

I want to plot the `df.speed`, its unit is `1`. If I do `df['speed'].hist()`, the grouping would make them too broad, like this:

[image]

Here the grouping for each `rectangle` is 10, How can I make it into 1?

I only see there is a `bin` parameter, but it is the overall count of the groups.

Comment: pass in the `bins` kwarg with the bin edges you would like to use.

Comment: @tcaswell thanks for the prompt, now I find the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram