# How to calculate upper and lower values of bins of equal density histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, density-plot

I have a range of positive integers ranging from 250-1200, with a normal distribution. I have found the answer to creating bins of equal density ([Matplotlib: How to make a histogram with bins of equal area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649342/matplotlib-how-to-make-a-histogram-with-bins-of-equal-area)). What I am actually looking for is to be able to retrieve the upper and lower boundaries of each bin. Is there a library/function that exists for this? or can this information be pulled out from matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the code provided in the question you linked:

```py
def histedges_equalN(x, nbin):
    npt = len(x)
    return np.interp(np.linspace(0, npt, nbin + 1),
                     np.arange(npt),
                     np.sort(x))

x = np.random.randn(1000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, histedges_equalN(x, 10))
```

`bins` is actually giving you the edges of each bin as you can read in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) of `hist` function:

[image]

Comment: that you for your rapid answer.

Comment: I have also added an example.

Comment: not sure if this is giving me what I need. I am looking to generate bins that have an equal areas of density. I believe this still shows an equal-bin width histogram. I possibly need to play around with the statistic variable.

Comment: sorry! I have edited my answer! Hope it helps!

Comment: fantastic. way simpler than I expected. I am truly grateful.

Comment: I have also added the link to the matplotlib `hist` function, look at `bins`.