# How do you select a custom bin size for a 2D histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I already know how to set the bin size for a 1D histogram after looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram),but I don't know how to do this for a 2D histogram. I have referred to both the [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) pages for the 2D histograms, but all my attempts to adjust the bin size did not work/run.I want my bins to have a length of 20 and a width of 2.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

dataX = np.random.uniform(-50,50,100)
dataY = np.random.uniform(-50,50,100)

binWidth = 2.0
binLength = 20.0

xMin = min(dataX)
xMax = max(dataX)
yMin = min(dataY)
yMax = max(dataY)

#this and all other similar attempts that I have tried did not run
np.histogram2d(dataX, dataY, bins = np.arange((xMin,xMax + binWidth),(yMin,yMin +binLength),(binWidth,binLength)))
```

Looking forward to your hints/help/advice.

Comment: Your usage of `np.arange` is wrong. For `hist2d` you can provide an array rather than a tuple: `bins = [x,y]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do e.g.

```
plt.hist2d(dataX, dataY, bins = [np.arange(xMin, xMax, binWidth), np.arange(yMin, yMax, binLength)])
```

bins accepts integers or arrays for defining the number of bins or their edges, each of it either once for both dimensions or in a list with two entries to give two different definietions for x and y.

From the docs:

> bins : int or array_like or [int, int] or [array, array], optional
>
> The bin specification:
>
> ```
>    If int, the number of bins for the two dimensions (nx=ny=bins).
>    If array_like, the bin edges for the two dimensions (x_edges=y_edges=bins).
>    If [int, int], the number of bins in each dimension (nx, ny = bins).
>    If [array, array], the bin edges in each dimension (x_edges, y_edges = bins).
>    A combination [int, array] or [array, int], where int is the number of bins and array is the bin edges.
> ```