# How to increase the plot_importance bar width in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the below bar chart generated by using `plot_importance`.

[image]

I increase the fontsize of `title`, `xlabel`, `ylabel`, `xticks` and `yticks` by using below code snippet:

```
plot_importance(clf)
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)
plt.title("Feature importance", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel("F score", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Features", fontsize=16)
```

But I also need to increase the **blue bar** width and corresponding **score** fontsize inside the plot.

How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram

Comment: Just use a paramater `width=0.5` or some other value you like in `plot_importance(clf), width=0.5`

Comment: @Bazingaa , there is no `width` parameter in [plot_importance()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_importance). BUT there is height parameter which solve my problem. :)

Comment: @NasirIslamSujan: If you read the parameters, it says "kwargs – Other keywords passed to ax.barh()". And `width` is one of the kwargs of `ax.barh()`

Comment: The signature of `barh(y, width, height=0.8)` means you can change the `height` to get a wider horizontal bar (that's somehow confusing, as the width of a horizontal bar is the height of a vertical bar).

Comment: That's really confusing. The height and width should be defined w.r.t the corresponding axis and not just x-axis

Comment: @Bazingaa I think there were discussions about that already, but I guess it makes sense not to change it now, to keep API breaking changes at minimum.

Comment: I think the `height` parameter is what you are looking for, set it to a value between 0 and 1.