# How to have equally distribution of bins when they have different size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to creating histograms with Matplotlib. I would like to create a histogram similar to this

[image]

As you can see, there are different size ranges (e.g. the first bar is only 50bp and the second is 400) but they are equally distributed. How can I do this?

The one I am doing looks like this

[image]

I know the first histogram has been developed with seaborn but I cannot install seaborn in the HPC I am using. Can I do this with matplotlib?

My code is

```
fig =figure(figsize =(16,6))

bins = [50,500,1000,10000,50000,100000,200000,500000,1000000]

patches = plt.hist(loss, bins = bins,
                   rwidth =0.85)

# define minor ticks and draw a grid with them
minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(2)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
plt.grid(which='minor', color='white', lw = 0.5)

# x ticks
xticks = [(bins[idx+1] + value)/2 for idx, value in enumerate(bins[:-1])]
xticks_labels = [ "{:.2f}\nto\n{:.2f}".format(value, bins[idx+1]) for idx, value in enumerate(bins[:-1])]
plt.xticks(xticks, labels = xticks_labels)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bin size in Matplotlib (Histogram)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986986/bin-size-in-matplotlib-histogram)

Comment: Use numpy.histogram and plt.bar